# Small issue in code execution, python card game simulation

Tags: python, simulation, game-engine

To whom this may concern,

This is some code to a card game simulation. (The game of war). When I run it I receive this error:

```
player0.append(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)] 
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not have a clue what the error is but maybe someone here does. Hopefully someone can resolve the issue for me. The code is, of course, still a work in progress so if there are any other bugs i would be happy to hear about them and their possible solutions.

```
import random

cards = ['ace', 'ace', 'ace', 'ace', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '8', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '9', '10', '10', '10', '10', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen', 'king', 'king', 'king', 'king']

order = ['ace', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'jack', 'queen', 'king'] 

print "shuffling cards" 
random.shuffle(cards,random.random)
print "lets play"
player0 = [cards[i] for i in range(len(cards)) if i % 2 == 1]

player1 = [cards[i] for i in range(len(cards)) if i % 2 == 0]

while (len(player0) > 0 or len(player1) > 0):

    nextcard0 = player0[0]
    nextcard1 = player1[0]

    cardplayed0 = order.index(nextcard0)

    cardplayed1 = order.index(nextcard1)

    if cardplayed0 > cardplayed1:

        player0.append(nextcard0)
        player0.append(nextcard1)
        player0.remove(nextcard0)
        player1.remove(nextcard1)

    elif cardplayed0 < cardplayed1:

        player1.append(nextcard1)
        player1.append(nextcard0)
        player1.remove(nextcard1)
        player0.remove(nextcard0)

    elif cardplayed0 == cardplayed1:
        while warcardvalue0 == warcardvalue1:
            if len(player0) >= 4:
                warcard0 = 4
            elif len(player0) < 4:
                warcard0 = len(player0)

            if len(player1) >= 4:
                warcard1 = 4
            elif len(player1) < 4:
                warcard1 = len(player1)


            warcardvalue0 = order.index(warcard0)
            warcardvalue1 = order.index(warcard1)

            if warcardvalue0 > warcardvalue1:
                player0.append(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)]
                player0.append(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)] 
                player0.remove(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)]
                player1.remove(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)] 

            elif warcardvalue0 < warcardvalue1:
                player1.append(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)]
                player1.append(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)] 
                player1.remove(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)]
                player0.remove(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)] 
            else
                print "another war!" 


if len(player1) == 0:
    print "player1 won!"
elif len(player0) == 0:
    print "player0 won!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line indicated in the error message

```
player0.append(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)] 
                                           ^
```

is missing a closing `)`

In fact all of these lines are missing the closing paren:

```
       if warcardvalue0 > warcardvalue1:
            player0.append(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)]
            player0.append(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)] 
            player0.remove(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)]
            player1.remove(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)] 

        elif warcardvalue0 < warcardvalue1:
            player1.append(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)]
            player1.append(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)] 
            player1.remove(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)]
            player0.remove(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)]
```

You may want to look through your code to make sure there are no other intstances of this problem.

*Also*, you might consider (and certainly would benefit) from an editor that does [paren matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_matching) for you, and would alert you to similar problems. I use one, and it's definitely worth it.

If you are interested in such editors, this might be a place to start explore options: [Top 10 Best Text Editors With Brace Matching](http://text-editor.pikimal.com/top/10/with-brace-matching/pikirank)

Comment: @ACollins If this solved your problem, please consider [accepting this answer by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). It'll reward us both with some points and marks this problem as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on every `append`/`remove` line.